# Problem installing packages( JLutils package)

Tags: r

I'm trying to in stall this package: JLutils
    With this following code

```
    install.packages("usethis")
library(usethis)
install.packages("Rcpp")
library(Rcpp)
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

devtools::install_github("larmarange/JLutils")
library(JLutils)
```

But I get this error message:

```
Downloading GitHub repo larmarange/JLutils@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\josem\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQFTMAZ\remotes1df0e4930ad\larmarange-JLutils-20eb88f/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'JLutils': (422ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'JLutils_1.18.0.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/josem/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'JLutils' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'JLutils'
* removing 'C:/Users/josem/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/JLutils'
**Error: Failed to install 'JLutils' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/josem/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQFTMAZ/file1df01db867a3/JLutils_1.18.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status**
```

Help me please, I don't know what is wrong with the package

Comment: The warning is converted into an error, which is causing things to fail. If you check [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html), under `'warn'` it says *"If 'warn' is two or larger all warnings are turned into errors"*. Since that warning (built under R version 3.6.3) should not stop other installations, it's safe to do (perhaps) `options(warn=0)` before trying to install `JLutils`.

Comment: @r2evans Great! I've already installed  the new version! It worked :)